# Отсутствие указания на нарушенные правила при модерации

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация, чат, бан

При использовании модераторских возможностей в чате модератор не указывает на конкретные нарушенные правила, ограничиваясь неоднозначными сообщениями уровня "прекрати это" или "тебя же предупреждали". При этом модератор активно участвует в словесной перепалке и сам "прекращать это" не собирается, продолжая усугублять неуютную ситуацию в чате и активно провоцируя участника.

Правильно ли поступает модератор? Нужна ли конкретика в модераторских предупреждениях? Что они должны содержать?

Comment: Это кстати хороший вопрос для кандидатов. К сожалению, по себе знаю, далеко не всегда есть время расписывать каждый чих в "работе".  Так что наверно проще система диспута/аппеляции с получением объяснения "по заказу".

Comment: Примеры, не голословность! Я такого ни разу не видел.